# Jquery event in the end of setting a text to an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want a JQuery event adapted to the fact of ending the set of a text input. the idea is to set off an alert dialog when i finish setting the text. i've try this but dosen't work like i want so any help please.

```
PS : #geocomplete the id of the input.

$("#geocomplete").keyup(function(){
      var x = $('input[name="lat"]').val();
      alert(x);
    });
```

Comment: Take a look at the `blur` event instead of keyup

Answer (score 0):

The keyup event occurs when a keyboard key is released.

The `keyup()` method triggers the keyup event, or attaches a function to run when a keyup event occurs.

The blur event occurs when an element loses focus.

The `blur()` method triggers the blur event, or attaches a function to run when a blur event occurs.

```
$("#geocomplete").blur(function(){
          var x = $('input[name="lat"]').val();
          alert(x);
        });
```

Try this

Comment: Please try to avoid code-only answers. Take the time to write a few statements on why it works or what it does.

Comment: @afsantos : check  my updated answer. why downvote? answer is correct.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter. Your answer showed up in the review page and I just commented. I've upvoted your edited answer.